# Duplicate records while sorting list descending

Tags: 2013, list, caml-query

I have implemeted a button which loads more data from list.

The page size is 12. Everytime I click button I get 12 records.

The query works fine if I use `Ascending = True` but when I change to `Ascending=False` and click on the button it gives me duplicate results. Why is it so?

Here is the query

```
Query = "<Where><And><Gt><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" + "<Value Type='Counter'>" + itemIndex + "</Value></Gt><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/>" + "<Value Type='Text'>Approved</Value></Eq></And></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE'></FieldRef></OrderBy>";
```

Comment: Should you not switch to `<Lt>` instead of `<Gt>` to make it consistant?

Comment: @RobertLindgren i get no records when i use <Lt> and Ascending = false

Comment: That is dependent on what you pass in as `itemIndex`, that too must be descending (so that you provide the lowest value that is currently displayed)

Comment: @RobertLindgren when i load list then i assign hidden textbox value like 
hdnLastIndex.Value = itemId;  Where itemId = item.ID.ToString();

Comment: Is `item` the first or last value you render? It should be the last one (the one with the lowest ID)

Comment: @RobertLindgren its the last item i render

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27592/discussion-between-happy-and-robert-lindgren).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me you have not a complete understanding of the logic you are trying to write?

Let me give you an example of how your code works now:

You have items `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

You retrieve them backwards (say you set `RowLimit=5` for now) so you will get:

```
10 9 8 7 6
```

Then you save the `6` in a variable

When the user click on "Show more" or whatever, you execute the query again,

This time your code says to get 5 items with an ID greater than `6` from the list, correct?

That will return you: `10 9 8 7` again!

By changing the logic to first pass in the `Int32.MaxValue` and swap the `Gt` to `Lt` (or just skip the that part of the query the first time you fetch items) you will still get

```
10 9 8 7 6
```

the first time, and then save the `6` in a variable

When the user clicks "show more" you now fetch items where ID is less than `6`, giving you the

```
5 4 3 2 1
```

as you want

Your query should be updated to look like this

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Lt>
            <FieldRef Name='ID'/>
            <Value Type='Integer'>" + itemIndex (where itemId should be the smallest number you got last time, or if it is the first query, it should be Integer.MaxValue) + "</Value>
        </Lt>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Status'/>
            <Value Type='Text'>Approved</Value>
        </Eq>
     </And>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False'></FieldRef>
</OrderBy>
```

and make sure that your `itemIndex`is the lowest lastly retrieved number or `Int32.MaxValue` (if it is the first fetch)

Comment: +1. Good explanation.